# How does AWS DynamoDB prevent from duplicated records by transaction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am building microservices in AWS and plan DynamoDB as my storage. Since the microservices will be accessed by thousands of clients and multiple tables (e.g. ECOMM_ORDERS and INVENTORY) will be updated inside DynamoDB. In each order, ECOMM_ORDERS will be inserted with an order record, and related products' inventory will be updated in INVENTORY table.

I reference [the official example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-example.html) but they do not work like traditional SQL Transaction (e.g. Begin Transaction, Rollback, Commit). How can I prevent duplicated records with DynamoDB transaction in my case? (By error handling? how should I rollback? how should I commit?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB transactions are an all-or-nothing operation.  The reads/writes will succeed or fail together, so there is no possibility that *some* operations in the transaction fail while others succeed.  The failure of a single write will cause all write operations in the transaction to be rolled back.

You can include [ConditionExpressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) in your `PutItem` operations to confirm `attribute_not_exists(primary_key)` on any of your items.  You can also use a [ConditionCheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ConditionCheck.html) in your transaction to confirm a condition during the transaction.

This [blog post](http://Simulating%20Amazon%20DynamoDB%20unique%20constraints%20using%20transactions) gives some good examples of using transactions to simulate unique constraints.

Also, from [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/):

> Items are not locked during a transaction. DynamoDB transactions
> provide serializable isolation. If an item is modified outside of a
> transaction while the transaction is in progress, the transaction is
> canceled and an exception is thrown with details about which item or
> items caused the exception.